# kendo angular2 TabstripComponent error

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-tabstrip

It was all working fine. After updating to latest packages now I am getting following error :

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./TabstripComponent class
>   TabstripComponent - inline template:29:26 caused by: Cannot read
>   property 'templateRef' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'templateRef' of undefined

All other kendo angular 2 controls are working fine except this TabstripComponent

Please share your thoughts how to rectify this issue.

EDITED:

Here is the code

In the component html page,

```html
<kendo-tabstrip (select)="onTabSelected($event)"> 
        <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'General'" [selected]="true">
            <district-general [generalComponentModel]="generalComponentModel" 
                (onExportChartImage)="onExportChartImage($event)" 
                (onExportClick)="onExportClick($event)">
            </district-general>
        </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
        <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Student'">
            <district-student [studentComponentModel]="studentComponentModel" (onExportChartImage)="onExportChartImage($event)"></district-student>
        </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
        <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Staff'">
            <district-staff [staffComponentModel]="staffComponentModel" (onExportChartImage)="onExportChartImage($event)"></district-staff>
        </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
        <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Longitudinal'">
            <district-longitudinal [longitudinalComponentModel]="longitudinalComponentModel" (onExportChartImage)="onExportChartImage($event)"></district-longitudinal>
        </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
    </kendo-tabstrip>
```

In app module page it has been declared and used like :

```ts
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [
    App,
    About,
    Home,
    ......
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    .......
    .......
    LayoutModule, 
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
    ENV_PROVIDERS,
    APP_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  // I am using web pack for this angular2 application
}
```

and in package.json dependencies

```
"@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^0.17.0",
```

Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it is working good with downgraded package. Please let me know if anyone came across same kind of issue.

```
"@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^0.11.0",
```